# Recognize if string contains geographical references

Tags: java, geolocation, ontology, named-entity-recognition, gis

How is it possible, in Java, to understand whether a `String` value (e.g., coming from user-generated content) contains a geographical reference? That is,

- names of cities
- addresses
- states

My current solution is to submit to a Geolocation API ([this one](https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/index.html) in particular) the string, so that if some match with some real location is found, then its coordinates are extracted.

(Related question on this approach: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181081/determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-geographic-location?rq=1))

However, some strings bring to errors. For instance, given the string location `"everywhere"`, which  is not meant to reflect any geographical location, actually returns a result in USA.

I identified two possible solutions, i.e., either ontologies or entity recognition strategies. However, I would like to ask which is the best solution (i.e., lowest impact in cost and time).

Comment: Doing this with any reliability sounds like a strong-AI problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now as far as I know, there aren't any methods in java. You have to do it by hand(String paring).

Now lets think about the problem logically:

**names of cities**: This is just a normal string. Only way is to compare it over all the name of cities in the world. You have to get all words in the String and compare every word to the list of all the cities in the world.(you can optimize in the comparison, but still you can't speed it much)

**addresses**: This easier if your address has starts(or has) some special characters.

**states**: Same as name of cities.

Comment: This should be a really easy-to-implement solution. However, I think NLP is way far more complicated. For instance, what if instead of a city I specify in my string the name of a village? The needed "cities/villages/nations" taxonomy would be really large... (and I don't know where to retrieve an enough rich list).

Comment: If you can try to define a structure of you string, It would be much easier that way. For example, City Name , Location, ...

Comment: Yes, this is true, but suppose the string is not constrained by any structure, since its is coming, e.g., from user-generated content. In that case you cannot force a structure on the generated string, and thus it is more difficult to get the real nature of the string content.

Comment: @Eleanore As the comment under your question says, this sounds like a problem in Pattern Recognition. I don't have that background to help. Trying to look at some algorithms in that field. Sounds like a classic problem there.